# Symfony2 ORM Entities, ManyToOne bidirectional

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-one

i have the following entities in Symfony2, a products entity and a comments entity.

The products entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $name;
```

The comments entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="productComment")
*/
class ProductComment
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\ProductsBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="comments")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $product;
}
```

My problem it's that i don't know how to get the comments from a product objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a `comments` property into the `Product` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\ProductsBundle\Entity\ProductComment", mappedBy="product")
 */
private $comments;
```

And then use

```
$product->getComments();
```